# How to override element.style in Wordpress navigation bar (menu)?

Tags: wordpress

First of all, a link to my site: **http://jakubplech.pl/**.

You can see a grey, centered horizontal menu in there. If you look at it, you'll get:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation position-default fixed" role="navigation" style="width: 1349px;">
```

I want nothing more that to change that width to auto, but it is an element.style of the theme and I have no idea how to refer to it (every change in custom CSS I did so far started with a dot). I read that i could use an !important trick, but since I don't know how to refer to it, it is impossible for me.

I'm dying to know the answer for this - if anyone could help me it would save me hours of frustration. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use its class like so:

```
.main-navigation {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: The first one (.main-navigation) works - thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer, could you please confirm it so others can benefit? Thank you.

Comment: Dont't exactly know what you mean by confirming, but I hereby state that Sheedo's answer works perfectly :)

Comment: You'll see a tick mark under the answer's votes. Click on it :)